# Modify Build Definition (Azure + Team Foundation Service)

Tags: azure, build, tfs, azure-devops

We have CI working from Team Foundation Service -> Azure Web Site, however, I am a bit stuck.  I went in to modify the build configuration through VS (e.g., add a description to the build configuration) and I get a validation error.  It creates the build definition with the following value for the drop folder: #/.

E.g., Copy build output to the following drop folder: #/

This is invalid, but I didn't want to mess with the configuration.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not running update 3 for Visual Studio.  Once this was installed (I just repaved my machine), this was resolved.